# Excel VBA - Save PDFs into one email instead of creating multiple separate emails

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am trying to save multiple PDFs into one email attachment. However, the below code is creating an email per PDF. I would like to attach all my PDFs into one email instead.

Sub mail()

```
Dim WksAct As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer
Dim MySheet As String, myFile As String
Dim OutlookApp As Object, MItem As Object

Set WksAct = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Activity")
LastRow = WksAct.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
    
    If WksAct.Range("B" & i).Value < 0 Then
        MySheet = WksAct.Range("A" & i).Value
        myFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & MySheet & ".pdf"
        Sheets(MySheet).ExportAsFixedFormat _
                                            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                            Filename:=myFile, _
                                            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                            OpenAfterPublish:=False
        
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
        With MItem
            .To = "test@mail.com"
            .Subject = "my Subject - To be adapted!"
            .Body = " Please find... "
            .Attachments.Add myFile
            .Display
            ' .Send
        End With
    End If
    
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Per your code, it looks like you're creating a new pdf and creating a new e-mail *FOR EACH ITERATION OF LOOP*.  Q: Is that really what you want to do?  SUGGESTION: Maybe you want to 1) move "create email" (`Create MItem`) *ABOVE*  the loop, 2) continue generating pdfs inside the loop, but 3) just add (Mitem.Attachments.Add` each iteration.  Try it, see if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Should probably move everything from `Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` to `End With` except for `.Attachments.Add myFile` to outside the loop. And amend to `MItem.Attachments.Add myFile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestions**

1. When working with rows in Excel, use `Long` and not `Integer`. You may get an overflow error.
2. Create the Outlook Object once instead of doing it in a loop.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Mail()
    Dim WksAct As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Integer
    Dim MySheet As String, myFile As String
    Dim OutlookApp As Object, MItem As Object
    
    '~~> Work with Outlook Object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    '~~> Create the email
    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    With MItem
        .To = "test@mail.com"
        .Subject = "my Subject - To be adapted!"
        .Body = " Please find... "
    End With
    
    Set WksAct = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Activity")
    
    With WksAct
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If .Range("B" & i).Value2 < 0 Then
                MySheet = .Range("A" & i).Value2
                
                myFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & MySheet & ".pdf"
                
                Sheets(MySheet).ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=myFile, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=False
                
                '~~> Give time for the save to happen
                DoEvents
                
                '~~> Attach the file
                MItem.Attachments.Add myFile
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    '~~> Show the email
    MItem.Display
End Sub
```

**Alternative**

An alternative would be to create the email in the end and add all pdfs in one go. For example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Mail()
    Dim WksAct As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Integer
    Dim MySheet As String, myFile As String
    Dim OutlookApp As Object, MItem As Object
           
    Set WksAct = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Activity")
    
    With WksAct
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If .Range("B" & i).Value2 < 0 Then
                MySheet = .Range("A" & i).Value2
                
                myFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & MySheet & ".pdf"
                
                Sheets(MySheet).ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=myFile, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=False
                
                '~~> Give time for the save to happen
                DoEvents
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    Dim StrFile As String
    
    '~~> Check if any pdfs were created and then
    '~~> create the email
    StrFile = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.pdf")
    If StrFile <> "" Then
        '~~> Work with Outlook Object
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        '~~> Create the email
        Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
        With MItem
            .To = "test@mail.com"
            .Subject = "my Subject - To be adapted!"
            .Body = " Please find... "
        
            '~~> Loop through all pdf and then add them
            Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
                MItem.Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & StrFile
                StrFile = Dir
            Loop

            '~~> Show the email
            .Display
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```